# Generate firebase dynamic links using node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

i want to generate firebase dynamic links using node js and firebase SDK, i configured the SDK and installed firebase-admin, now i can create users with email and password, using node js and flutter SDK.

but when i try to create dynamic link, i get an error which says : `admin.dynamicLinks is not a function`.

here is my configuration and controller codes.

config

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import serviceAccount from "./firebaseConfig.mjs";


// FIREBASE CONFIG
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEYFIREBASE,
  appId: process.env.APPID,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENTID,
};

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

initializeApp({ credential: firebaseConfig });
```

and here is the controller :

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";

const createQrCode = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const destinationUrl = "https://smartsystem.com";

    const dynamicLinkParams = {
      domainUriPrefix: "https://smartsystem.page.link",
      link: destinationUrl,
      androidInfo: {
        androidPackageName: null,
      },
      iosInfo: {
        iosBundleId: null,
      },
    };

// here is the function (generating dynamic link)
    const dynamicLink = await admin
      .dynamicLinks()
      .createDynamicLink(dynamicLinkParams);

    res.status(200).json({
      success: "OK",
      dynamicLink,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error.message, 500);
  }
};
```

i tried to create user with this firebase SDK and i could, but i have no idea why i cant to do that to dynamic link, tried with another project, but still got same error..

im using node js V16.14.2